# Conditions on morphism of coverings to be a covering

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X, Y, Z$ be topological spaces with $X$ connected, $p: Y \to X$ and $q: Z \to X$ be covering maps and $f: Y \to Z$ a continuous function, such that $p = q \circ f$. Is $f$ necessarily a covering?

I know that if $X$ is locally connected then it must be, but I am wondering if I can drop that assumption.

What if we don't assume that $X$ is locally connected, but we assume that covering maps $p$ and $q$ have finite fibers? Is $f$ a covering map itself then?

Comment: I think you should try to verify the lifting property.

Comment: What did you mean by covering?

Comment: A covering map, as defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space

Comment: Even in the locally connected case you need additional requirements. In general $f$ will not be surjective. Perhaps you want to assume that $X,Y,Z$ are connected?